# Rails has_one :through Association for Self-Referential 1-to-1-to-1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design, associations

I have a `Factsheet` model which holds an assortment of publications, including alternate language versions.  The different language versions should be kept separate as individual records (because they can be ordered/updated/etc. separately), but I'm trying to associate them to each other so that you can easily tell when one publication is the Spanish (or Chinese, etc.) version of the other.

I would like to use a `:through` association so that the relationship is symmetric, e.g. if English Factsheet A has a Spanish version Factsheet B, then similarly Factsheet B has an English version Factsheet A.

Here are my models:

```
class Factsheet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :publications_language_relationships
  has_one :en, :through  => :publications_language_relationships
  has_one :es, :through  => :publications_language_relationships
  has_one :zh, :through  => :publications_language_relationships #zh = Chinese

  # other stuff
end
```

and...

```
# Table name: publications_language_relationships
#
#  en_id      :integer
#  es_id      :integer
#  zh_id      :integer
#
class PublicationsLanguageRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :en, :class_name => 'Factsheet'
  belongs_to :es, :class_name => 'Factsheet'
  belongs_to :zh, :class_name => 'Factsheet'
end
```

But when I fire up a Rails console to check to see if that works at all...

```
$ fs = Factsheet.last
=> #<Factsheet id: 5, title: "Despu\xC3\xA9s de un diagn\xC3\xB3stico de c\xC3\
xA1ncer de seno: Con...", backend_code: "fs_after_bc_diagnosis_es", language: 
"es", created_at: "2010-11-30 21:23:01", updated_at: "2010-12-06 16:13:23">

$ fs.en
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: publicati
ons_language_relationships.factsheet_id: SELECT "factsheets".* FROM "factsheets"
 INNER JOIN "publications_language_relationships" ON "factsheets".id = "publicat
ions_language_relationships".en_id WHERE (("publications_language_relationships"
.factsheet_id = 5)) LIMIT 1
```

So something's amiss with my associations, but I'm not quite sure what.  Thoughts?

Additionally, is this even a sound design for the data, or should I be doing something differently here?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this solution, but I think the general architectural direction you want to take is not really through the :through relationship, but rather something like:

```
class Factsheet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :publications_language_relationships

   named_scope :translation, lambda { |trans|
      { :conditions => ["publications_language_relationships = ?", trans.to_s ] , 
        :joins => :publications_language_relationships 
      }
    }

  # other stuff
end

class PublicationsLanguageRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :fact_sheet
end
```

And then, I think you'd call the translations in your controller/views something like this:

```
#controller
def show
   @fact_sheet = FactSheet.find( params[:id] ) # to load up the FactSheet
end

#view (to get the right translation)
@fact_sheet.translation(:en) #for english
```

I don't think this is absolutely right, but it should get you on the path anyway.